# what is the preferred approach for creating a pipeline in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I've used Jenkins a bit here and there but this is my first time to create a pipeline in Jenkins.  What is the preferred tool these days for creating a new Jenkins pipeline?  Here's the main Jenkins docs page for pipelines:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

The url states:

> get started with Pipeline - covers how to define a Jenkins Pipeline
> (i.e. your Pipeline) through Blue Ocean, through the classic UI or in
> SCM

I viewed the Jenkins Blue Ocean docs page and it has this info towards the top of the page:

> Blue Ocean status Blue Ocean will not receive further functionality
> updates. Blue Ocean will continue to provide easy-to-use Pipeline
> visualization, but it will not be enhanced further. It will only
> receive selective updates for significant security issues or
> functional defects.

That passage gives me the impression that Blue Ocean may be in a somewhat deprecated state as the tool for creating new pipelines in Jenkins.  Is that the case?  What is the preferred tool these days for Jenkins admins to create a new pipeline in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using Blueocean as it's not going to receive any updates from Cloudbees.

Having said that, Jenkins Pipeline has a declarative syntax. So it doesn't really matter how you create it as long as you adhere to the correct syntax. The correct question you should be asking is where to store your Pipeline. Basically, you can embed the Pipeline in the Jenkins Job itself, or read the Pipeline from an SCM or you can add your pipeline as a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).